# Assigning values to a new column in R dataframe based on logical expression

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column in my R dataframe and assigning values based on logical expressions on other columns:

```
survey$session <- "0"

if(survey$delay == "0" && survey$intensive == "0") {survey$session <- "11"}
if(survey$delay == "0" && survey$intensive == "1") {survey$session <- "12"}
if(survey$delay == "1" && survey$intensive == "0") {survey$session <- "21"}
if(survey$delay == "1" && survey$intensive == "1") {survey$session <- "22"}
```

For some reason, only the 3rd row is actually assigning values and I end up with the entire column filled with "21".

Any idea why this would happen? TIA!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(survey)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(survey, 20))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing what the question asks for.

**1.** Use logical indices to assign in place.

```
survey <- data.frame(delay, intensive)

i0 <- survey$delay == "0"
i1 <- survey$delay == "1"
j0 <- survey$intensive == "0"
j1 <- survey$intensive == "1"
survey$session <- "0"
survey$session[i0 & j0] <- "11"
survey$session[i0 & j1] <- "12"
survey$session[i1 & j0] <- "21"
survey$session[i1 & j1] <- "22"
```

And clean up.

```
rm(i0, i1, j0, j1)
```

**2.** Use arithmetic, since the values to be assigned follow a pattern.

```
survey <- data.frame(delay, intensive)

survey$session <- "0"
survey$session <- with(survey, 10*(as.integer(delay) + 1) + as.integer(intensive) + 1)
```

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)
n <- 10
delay <- as.character(rbinom(n, 1, prob = 0.5))
intensive <- as.character(rbinom(n, 1, prob = 0.5))
```